# How to fill in the rest of the background with a solid color

Tags: html, css

Check out my code to see what I mean. I want the entire background to be black. However, the background is only black where there is text.

Here is picture:[image: example]

```
<div style="background-color:black">
    <img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:10px" height="400" width="400">
    <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Define "entire". As far as I can tell, the entire div's background is black. Do you mean the entire page?

Comment: will `body{background-color:black;}` do?

Comment: You should read a bit about styling and how to use it to control element margins and paddings.

Comment: I don't want the entire page's background to be black. I just want the entire div's background to be black. But for some reason, the background is only back (to the right of the image) where there is text.

Comment: Your div is only taking the height of the text.

Comment: You said you don't want the entire page background to be black - it is not. You said you only want the entire div background to be black - and it is. And then you go on to accept an answer that made the entire page background black...

Comment: Sorry, light. That IS what I wanted (only having the div background black), but nothing was getting the job done (until Obscure Geek recently posts); thus, I went with the next best option. Why so mad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem which was happening when you are trying to set

```
background-color: black;
```

for the div is that the div is taking the dimensions of text and not image. The background color property was being set correctly just the dimensions for the div were not set. Since the image height is 400 try

```
style="background-color: black; height: 400px;"
```

This will work for the div and allow you to add other elements to the body as the entire body will not be black.

**Addition:**

As per the image added, coloring the `body` background will not yield the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

**index.html**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="http://csc2.madonna.edu/~brabahy/hw5/images/Mercury1.jpg" style="float:left; margin-right:10px" height="400" width="400">
    <p style="color:brown">Mercury is the smallest planet, and it's closest to the Sun of the eight planets in the Solar System. It has an orbital period of about 88 Earth days.</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {background-color: black;}
```

Comment: This did work, actually! I just put the style in the <body> tag. <body style="background-color:black"